# Graph-X Not Showing Graphs

Tags: vb.net

I'm Using Following code to Show Graph using [Graph-X](http://graphx.codeplex.com) In My VB.Net Forms Application
But It Shows Only Zoom Control Bar And Nothing On Graph I don't know where's the problem

```
      Public Class GraphAreaExample
  Inherits GraphArea(Of DataVertex, DataEdge, BidirectionalGraph(Of DataVertex, DataEdge))
      End Class
'Graph data object
Public Class GraphExample
    Inherits BidirectionalGraph(Of DataVertex, DataEdge)
End Class

'Vertex data object
Public Class DataVertex
    Inherits VertexBase
    <XmlAttribute("text"), DefaultValue("")> _
    Public Property Text() As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class

'Edge data object
Public Class DataEdge
    Inherits EdgeBase(Of DataVertex)
    Public Sub New(ByVal source As DataVertex, ByVal target As DataVertex, Optional ByVal weight As Double = 1)
        MyBase.New(source, target, weight)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(Nothing, Nothing, 1)
    End Sub

    <XmlAttribute("text"), DefaultValue("")> _
    Public Property Text() As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function

End Class
Dim Rand As New Random()

        'Create data graph object
        Dim graph = New GraphExample()

        'Create and add vertices using some DataSource for ID's
        For Each item In DataSource.Take(100)
            graph.AddVertex(New DataVertex() With {.ID = item.ID, .Text = item.Text})
        Next item

        Dim vlist = graph.Vertices.ToList()
        'Generate random edges for the vertices
        For Each item In vlist
            If Rand.Next(0, 50) > 25 Then
                Continue For
            End If
            Dim vertex2 = vlist(Rand.Next(0, graph.VertexCount - 1))
            graph.AddEdge(New DataEdge(item, vertex2, Rand.Next(1, 50)) With {.Text = String.Format("{0} -> {1}",item, vertex2)})
        Next item
```

Xaml Code

```
xmlns:graphxctrl="clr-namespace:GraphX.Controls;assembly=GraphX"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShowcaseExample"  

   <graphxctrl:ZoomControl x:Name="gg_zoomctrl">
         <local:GraphAreaExample x:Name="gg_Area"/>
   </graphxctrl:ZoomControl>
```